# Android slidemenu paint over contents

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using this slide menu java class https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu/commits/master but I don't know how do I paint my slide menu over activity contents this is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/smenu"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/mainBg"
      android:weightSum="12"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
</com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder>
```

this is results something like this photo :
[image: A]

but I need to do something like this one:
[image: B]

is there any chance to do this?

Comment: There is something called Navigation Drawer as a part of Android design guidelines which solves excatly the problem you have: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I need to create it with that slidemenu, I do exactly know there is a navigation drawer exists...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout 
 android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/> 



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_wraper"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#DDFAFAFA"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"

     />    

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Where first child is your content, and second one is your menu holder. 
You can instantinate it like this :

```
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_wrapper);

    String[] names = { "Create", "Show up", "Hide out", "WebView", "Registration", "LogIn View" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

And finally the DrawerClickListener class:

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {             
        switch (position) {

        case 0: break;
            case 1: break;
            }
    }
```